# Sylius emails not delivered however debug shows that it sent

Tags: php, email, symfony, swiftmailer, sylius

Sylius order confirmation and order comment emails doesnt delivered however its spooled in debug. Also misterious that the registration and recovery emails are delivered fine.
Also "Alternative part" text appears at the end of the email.

```
sylius.mailer.transport: smtp <br>
sylius.mailer.host: localhost <br>
sylius.mailer.port: 25
```

Tried the port with null and the host with 127.0.0.1 but none of the 4 permutation worked.. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the Symfony mailer configuration

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/email.html

If you have a Gmail account you can easily configure it

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/gmail.html

Hope this helps